# how to fix ! operator giving null value

Tags: flutter, dart, null

Null operator issue flutter

got an issue where the app crash because of null value but when i be using the app for a while then add this and hot reload the app it works

```
'${( controller.currentWeatherData.main!.temp! - 273.15).round().toString()}\u2103',
```

couldn't tell how to fix it

tried using ? but have another bug

```
Text(
  '${(controller.currentWeatherData.main!.temp! - 273.15).round().toString()}\u2103',
  //  'round',
  style: Theme.of(context)
      .textTheme
      .headline2!
      .copyWith(
          fontSize:
              AppDime.md_14,
          // color:
          //     Colors.black45,
          fontFamily:
              'flutterfonts'),
),
```

Comment: null checked used on a null variable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a null check first instead of using null-assert,

```dart
if(controller.currentWeatherData.main?.temp!=null) 
   Text( '${( controller.currentWeatherData.main!.temp - 273.15).round().toString()}\u2103',)
 else Text("Got null"),
```

Or just default value on case can be

```dart
'${((controller.currentWeatherData.main?.temp?? 0) - 273.15).round().toString()}\u2103'
```

Comment: hi thanks for help but didn't work 

'${(controller.currentWeatherData.main?.temp ?? 0 - 273.15).round().toString()}\u2103',

it doesn't subtact the number 273.15 it adds it to the value i get instead

Comment: try `'${((controller.currentWeatherData.main?.temp?? 0 )- 273.15).round().toString()}\u2103'`

Comment: The issue was it was performing operation after ?? on null case